Error uploading files from Nextjs server to ImageKit (413 Payload too large)
I'm getting this error when i'm uploading a file to my image cdn provider (ImageKit). 413 (Payload Too Large). it happened when i upload multiple files. The app works well while i upload just one file.
It just happens in production.
enter image description here
CODE REACT
async function handleSubmitImage(formData) {
setLoader(true);
const renamedFormData = renameFormDataKeys(formData);
const toUpload = [];

try {
  for (let index = 0; index < formData.length; index++) {
    const element = formData[index];
    const data = await handleCreateGallery(renamedFormData, user.id, element.id);

    if (data) {
      toUpload.push(data.url);
      // Actualizar el estado de la imagen
      setTempImages((prevState) =>
        prevState.map((el) => el.id === data.id ? { ...el, loaded: true } : el)
      );

      // Bloque de código a ejecutar después de que se haya enviado correctamente una imagen
      console.log("La imagen se envió correctamente");
      // Aquí puedes ejecutar cualquier código adicional que necesites después de enviar una imagen
    }
  }

  updateProfile(toUpload);
  setIsLoaded(true);
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error en la actualización del estado:", error);
  // Manejar el error apropiadamente
} finally {
  setLoader(false);
}

}
I have tried to upload one image per request.
